# Branch-agnostic history of a file on github?

Tags: github, branch, revision-history

While googling, I stumbled on [this file](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6296e324485f1d457e561824a3a8ddcafc3a08d8/src/library/scala/reflect/DynamicProxy.scala) living in an old github repository branch.

Now, when I switch to a more recent branch it just shows me `404 - not found`.

I would like to know:

- was this file moved, or was it just deleted?
- if it was deleted, at which point was it deleted?

I don't feel like going through every branch searching for a file that may have been long gone... is there a practical thing I could do?

PS: I don't care about this particular file anymore, but that's a problem I've been facing several times.

Comment: To find out what happened with the file, just click the [History](https://github.com/scala/scala/commits/6296e324485f1d457e561824a3a8ddcafc3a08d8/src/library/scala/reflect/DynamicProxy.scala). Check the most recent commit and you'll see it was renamed.

Comment: No, that doesn't work: [the history](https://github.com/scala/scala/commits/6296e324485f1d457e561824a3a8ddcafc3a08d8/src/library/scala/reflect/DynamicProxy.scala) only contains commits in the current branch! In the last commit on that branch, the file was not renamed.

Comment: I can see the commit [scala.reflect.api: Reporters => FrontEnds](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/89fd256787695774771b5d4509de493271267585). Could not find in the branch 2.11.x though, which is mentioned on the top. This might be case, when link to file is available, but history is different, e.g. when force pushed. How did you find this file?

Comment: Look at the commit's diff: only a line changed for this file -- it's not a move commit! It's not relevant how I found this file (by Googling); this is a general problem I've had several times: you can't see the global history of the file, just the history in a particular branch.

Comment: I see now. Yes, that's how git works, it's not file-centered.